# Android: how to get a pointer to the Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have application with a `Service`. This service starts worker `Thread`, and this thread needs a pointer to an instance of Service (it calls some methods of this service).

Now i just pass `this` pointer from `Service`'s `onCreate()` method to my own `Runnable` constructor, but it works correctly until i close my app. When app is restarted, something becomes really wrong with pointers. I still can't figure out what especially is wrong, but it seems like pointer to my instance of Service is a pointer to strange another instance of Service, and pointer to my `Runnable` is wrong too.

If i **kill** my app, then next time it works correctly, but after restart the same issues is taking place.

I suspect that i can't pass `this` pointer from `onCreate()` method of Service, but then, how can i get pointer to instance of my Service from the thread that starts from `onCreate()` method?

**UPDATE**: I just figured out that i have exactly the same [singleton issue](http://goo.gl/mj8J0). The `Runnable` was a singleton. But i still can't find any good solution except not to use singletons in Android at all. Maybe, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this thread needs a pointer to an instance of Service (it calls some methods of this service).

There are no pointers in Java. The Java equivalent would be "object reference".

> until i close my app

There is no such concept as "closing" an "app" in Android.

> I still can't figure out what especially is wrong, but it seems like pointer to my instance of Service is a pointer to strange another instance of Service, and pointer to my Runnable is wrong too.

That is eminently possible, if you stopped the original `Service` and leaked the thread, then started up the `Service` again. You may well have wound up with two threads, one holding a defunct copy of your `Service`.

> how can i get pointer to instance of my Service from the thread that starts from onCreate() method?

That is not your problem. Your problem, whatever it is, lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for wrong terminology, but about an "app": in system settings i can go to exactly "application management", and i can stop (not close, yes, but stop) my installed "application". I think that right term would be Activity? And, i'd like to check back: in general, is this OK to pass `this` reference to something in `Service.onCreate()`?

Comment: @dimonomid: "in system settings i can go to exactly "application management", and i can stop (not close, yes, but stop) my installed "application"." -- users do not usually do this. " is this OK to pass this reference to something in Service.onCreate()?" -- generally, yes.

Comment: i didn't say that users should do this, i just tried to explain why i used "app" term.  Well, i found a bug, thanks again: there was a singleton issue. I updated my question, could you please look at this update and maybe suggest something?

Comment: @dimonomid: Static data members (a.k.a., singletons) are not intrinsically a problem in Android, other than being a likely source of memory leaks. The question you linked to was from somebody with a buggy library. Your update to your question does not explain what you think your problem is in sufficient detail for anyone to give you assistance.